# Service Fabric: Plugins vs. Application Types

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm developing a Service Fabric-based trading platform that will host hundreds of different long-running trading algorithms, all of which conform to a common interface and share a good deal of common code but can be vastly different in their internal specifics.  I could model each of the different algos as an application type (which I'd dynamically load) but given the large number of different algos I have to wonder if in makes more sense to create a single Plugin Runner application type then implement the algos as plugins.

In a  related question, I understand how to implement a plugin architecture, in general, but I'm not quite sure where one would place the actual plugins in order to be discoverable by an instance running on Service Fabric.

Anyway, thanks for your help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Both approaches can work I think. Using lots of Application Types adds the (significant) overhead of running lots of processes, but allows you to use and upgrade multiple versions of the same algorithm running simultaneously.
   Using the plugin approach requires you to deal with versioning yourself.

   Using the Application approach probably requires some kind of request router, while the 
   plugin service could make it's own decisions (if it's stateless).
2. You can create a Stateful service that acts as the plugin repository, or mount a file share, or use a database, no restrictions from the platform here. You can use naming conventions to locate the proper plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful answer.  Any idea where / how to put the plugins so they can be found by the Azure Service Fabric at runtime?  I'm thinking the DevOps of the thing...

Comment: Maybe something like this: when requesting algo "A v1", look for an assembly by that name: "A" and version "1". Download the assembly from a repository (like in 2. above) put it in your working dir and load it using Assembly.Load("A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"); Use reflection to find and instantiate it.

Comment: You can also have "files" that you deploy along-side your code. All services have 2 data packages that gets deployed with the application, "Code" and "Config". These packages are versioned independently and can be deployed independently. Furthermore, you can add your own package in the same style to a service where you can have your plugins. You can then deploy and version this package independently of your code.
Look here for more infomation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-model

Answer (score 0):

The following approach could work if an application upgrade is acceptable to you when changing the set of plugins needed for a given application instance.

Recall that Service Fabric apps must be packaged before deployment or upgrade. Using either msbuild tasks or Powershell, you could copy your plugin dlls to the plugin runner service's code package as a post-packaging step prior to the app upgrade. Then your plugin dlls would be available to the service at startup using `Assembly.Load` and the code package's path, available in your service implementation's `Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetCodePackageObject("Your-Code-Package-Name").Path` property. The code package's name is defined in `ServiceManifest.xml`, and is named `Code` by default.